# Are all of the features in Javascript API in XAML/C# API?

Tags: c#, javascript, xaml, windows-8

For Windows 8 ans RT, is all of the features in the JavaScript API also in the XAML/C# for Windows 8/RT development?  I heard that it complements a high number of the API features, but is not 100%.

Comment: XAML in it's self does not have access to the windows rt API, you use c# or some other .net language to access the windows RT API...

Comment: Compared to what? In WinRT you **do not have** everything you have in Win32 but what you have there is available for every language you can use (JavaScript/C#/C++...). Of course what you can do in XAML and in HTML is different (so yes, in HTML you do not have all WPF features...)

Comment: @Adriano I'm not asking in comparison of WinRT to Windows 8, i'm asking the API features available in C#, do they match the JavaScript API capabilities?

Comment: In C# you can compile both for desktop application and for Metro (ooops Modern UI), if you compile for Metro you have the same API.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes and no:

1. Yes, most of the API paradigms are the same.
2. No, they are not called the same things.
3. No, they are not called in the same ways.
4. No, they do not all operate in the same fashion (return values, et cetera).

As JS runs primarily on top of HTML, and JS is single-thread-only, and loosely-typed, and has a heritage based on lambdas and closure/scope passing, instead of traditional class-construction, the DOM-libraries and peculiarities are also different from those of C# + XAML.

So the question boils down to what it is you're talking about:
If your question is:
"*can I access Windows RT features in the language of my choice, through a MS-specific library?*"
The answer is yes.

If your question is:
"*can I do all things in JS/HTML that I can do in C#/XAML or C++?*"
The answer is no.

If your question is:
"*does my knowledge of WinRT method-calls/API-footprint in language X translate directly

(ie: [CTRL+X|CTRL+C],CTRL+V/verbatim), to language Y?*"
The answer is no.

So the key to getting the most out of this is to know what is and is not a part of the RT specification.
XBox360 controller support, for instance:
Not supported in JS (at least not the last time I checked the spec -- during dev releases).

Why not?
It's not a supported part of WinRT, ergo, not a part of the RT library, ergo, inaccessible from the JS RT library.
But using DirectInput/XInput in C# or C++, in an RT app, you can have full support for a 360 controller.

On the other hand, all things which are actually supported in the WinRT library (file-access, webcam/audio access, Promises, etc), are available (accessible/behaving in language-specific ways) inside of the library, regardless of language, and all operate at roughly the same speed, in terms of method-calls (as each language basically has a wrapper to access C++ implementations), but not necessarily final run-time (an HTML5 canvas application of a webcam app might be slower than a C++ app... no surprise).

Comment: "can I do all things in JS/HTML that I can do in C#/XAML or C++?" answer is **yes** because both stand on WinRT. "does my knowledge of WinRT method-calls/API-footprint in language X translate to language Y?" answer is **yes** again (limited to WinRT API, of course languages are different and to write an app in JS + HTML vs C#/C++ + XAML is very very different because of syntax and coding standards). Basically for Metro what you can do in C#/XAML can be done in JS/HTML too (even if I would think twice before to do it...)

Comment: @Adriano 1) No -- it's a yes if you assume that you *ONLY* use the WinRT library, it's a NO if you're talking about language-features/frameworks outside of WinRT. It ***IS*** possible to cross-compile custom implementations (to offer JS access to a C# wrapper for 360 Controller access), but again, that's beyond the scope of the question -- if a C++ programmer wants to put a 360 controller in the game, they can -- if a JS programmer wants to, they have to rely on the HTML5 API, eventually (or wrap an XInput implementation).

Comment: 2) The ***footprint*** of the APIs is different -- the method-names, cases for the method-names, expected-inputs, method-overloading, expected return statements, et cetera, are all different. Do all of the WinRT libraries support Promises/Deferred applications of code? Yes. Are they all accessed the exact same way (by typing the exact same thing, and inputting the exact same values, and getting the exact same object back, with the exact same methods/properties, with the exact same spelling/cases)? No. So the abstract knowledge of what you can do applies 100%. The direct cut/paste does not.

Comment: 1) PO pointed we're talking about WinRT only so I suppose this is all what he is interested to. By the way even if very limited you can have  multithread with JavaScript too (web workers and promises).

Comment: 2) I agree about the footprint, API is the same but how you use it must be used is specific of language features/look & feel.

Comment: @Adriano Yes, you absolutely can use workers. And they're handy, but really can not be treated the same as a fully multi-threaded application in another language. Especially not in IE, which doesn't support a large swath of the things which you'd use WW for, in other browsers (WebGL/audio api/etc). As for the OP, he's heard that Win8/WinRT development lets you do things in C# which you can't do in JS...  ...so a C# app on a Surface tablet might let you use a 360 controller - a JS app likely won't. Does he know why, or does he assume it's missing from the JS library? Who told him? Do they know?

Comment: You got my +1, I agree with your last comment